# Can any one answer this?

Tags: python, html, frontend, backend, web-development-server

connecting python program with HTML. when I click the HTML button I need output from that python program to display in the front end. please guide me in how to solve this problem.
I need to connect that python program to my web application how to do this connecting part?

Comment: Your question is too vague, what have you tried so far?  Look at a Flask tutorial in the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have a look at [flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/) its a python library with which you can do server side stuff (backend development)

there's also another popular library [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) which you can look for.